# Determine if Array or Object

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, rest

I've created a class to parse a JSON response.  The trouble I'm having is that one item is sometimes an array and others an object.  I've tried to come up with a workaround, but it always ends up giving me some other problem.

I'd like to have some sort of if or try statement that would let me determine what gets created.

pseudocode...

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Devices
    {   
        if(isArray){
        [DataMember(Name = "device")]
        public Device [] devicesArray { get; set; }}

        else{
        [DataMember(Name = "device")]
        public Device devicesObject { get; set; }}
    }
```

Using Dan's code I came up with the following solution, but now when I try to use it I have a casting issue.
"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'MItoJSON.Device'"

```
[DataContract]
    public class Devices
    {
        public object target;

        [DataMember(Name = "device")]
        public object Target
        {
            get { return this.target; }

            set
            {
                this.target = value;

                var array = this.target as Array;
                this.TargetValues = array ?? new[] { this.target };
            }
        }

        public Array TargetValues { get; private set; }
    }
```

Comment: Just model it as an array - for a single item it will be an array with one item.

Comment: that's what I was doing originally, but it failed to work.  The length of the array was always zero if there was only one item.  If I created it as an object, then it would work for single items.

Comment: I seriously doubt the length of the array was zero if you passed and array with one items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the target property as an object.  You could then create a helper property that handles whether the target is an array or a single object:

```
    private object target;

    public object Target
    {
        get { return this.target; }

        set
        {
            this.target = value;

            var array = this.target as Array;
            this.TargetValues = array ?? new[] { this.target };
        }
    }

    public Array TargetValues { get; private set; }
```